# Vue js router not loading page if i'm passing token from router.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue js with laravel api . i have defined router for forget password page in url i'm passing token . when i'm passing token then page not loading its coming not found.

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import ResetPasswordForm from './pages/ResetPasswordForm'
Vue.use(Router)
const routes = [{
  path: 'reset-password/:token',
  name: 'ResetPasswordForm',
  component: ResetPasswordForm
}]
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::any('{slug}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

please help me how to fixed out this issue.

Comment: yes this is SPA

Comment: only for reset-password/:token route not working

Comment: please check updated code

Comment: may i know what is your url with token may be some special chat is there that's why not wokring

Comment: `{slug}` only accounts for a single parameter. Once you introduce a `/` in the parameter, the route will fail to match subsequent routes. If you're using laravel 6/7/8, you can use `Route::fallback` instead which will match everything.